# Which method does pyQuil use to compile a Program?

Tags: programming, compiling, pyquil

I want to find out which method different compilers use to decompose a matrix into smaller gates. I went through the pyQuil code on github but could not find the answer there. Maybe i lost track of something. I would by highly interested in the methods used by PyQuil.

Answer (score 1):

Pyquil uses QuilC to compile programs to native gates: https://github.com/quil-lang/quilc